# Is there a way to permanently "assign" /dev/ names to removable USB devices

Tags: arch-linux, usb, raspberry-pi, devices

I have a GPS unit which attaches by a USB port to Raspberry Pi.  Because of the "mysterious" (to me) way the Arch Linux system that powers the Pi assigns /dev/ filenames, I never know if I'm going have contention between this USB device and other USB devices (and software) on the system. I would like to able to know permanently what this GPS is going to be called no matter when it is connected (i.e. before booting, after booting, etc.) Is it possible to achieve this level of determinacy through configuration?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021547/writing-udev-rule-for-usb-device

Comment: @Bib, this sounds like what I need but what is this "udev rules" facility that is described there?  I know nothing about it and would like to before I plunge into it. Update: this sounds like the info I am looking for: https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev  Bib, make your comment and answer and I'll credit you for it.

Comment: One question I continue to have after reading Seth Kenlon's excellent article mentioned above is: the article talks about "events" like plugging in a hard drive (onto a presumably running system).  What, if any event is generated when the USB device is plugged in BEFORE the system is booted?

Answer (score 2):

udev rules are rules used in relation to devices. These rules, amongst other things, can set permissions or rename devices.

They are constructed via text files in the `/etc/udev/rules.d` directory.

See [GPSD udev rules](https://github.com/biiont/gpsd/blob/master/gpsd.rules) & [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021547/writing-udev-rule-for-usb-device)

For instance, take the following rule:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0003", SYMLINK+="gps%n", RUN+="/lib/udev/gpsd.hotplug"
```

The idVendor & idProduct are attributes which are the USB device serial numbers which can be had from `lsusb`. Hopefully the rest should be self explanatory. One bit that is missing, is permissions, which can be set as:

> MODE="0666"

As for seeing the device on boot. It still works as the system is scanned by the udev process & kernel - I'm sure someone will come along and correct me on this.

When unplugging, you should have the corresponding line in your rule set:

```
ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/lib/udev/gpsd.hotplug"
```

Sorry for the brusk manner, it's late...

Comment: Brusque???? Are you kidding me?  I nearly got my head ripped off for asking this question on the Arch Linux forum because my Arch Linux was not x86-64.  You, by contrast, are a veritable fountain of useful and good-natured information.

Comment: okay: I downloaded the GPSD udev rules file you linked to to my Pi, I copied it to my /lib/udev/rules.d directory as 25-gspd.rules. I verified that the RUN file /lib/udev/gpsd.hotplug exists.  I rebooted but don't think it worked. cgps says gpsd isn't running and ps -ef reveals no gpsd process.  what could be wrong?

Comment: I assume you need to do `systemctl enable gpsd` which will start it on boot, and/or `systemctl start gpsd` which will start it manually.